# classnotfoundexception: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver for java program

Tags: java, mysql

i have an problem could anyone help me? i'm trying to connect to mysql using java but get an error

the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
```

code :

```
public static Connection c;

static String host = "localhost";
static String port = "3306";
static String database = "";
static String username = "root";
static String password = "";

public static void connect() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database, username, password);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you configured jdbc connector?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: i've added it into my project it exports with it and to run it i use this command java -cp connector2 -jar GCDSS.jar

Comment: public static Connection c;

    static String host = "localhost";
    static String port = "3306";
    static String database = "";
    static String username = "root";
    static String password = "";

    public static void connect() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

            c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + database, username, password);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: that's the code

Comment: Add this to question

Comment: the connector JAR name needs to appear in the classpath.  you don't appear to have the correct file name.

Comment: and how do i check the classpath in intelij idea?

Comment: The mysql jar file is obviously missing.

Comment: found the classpath how to add it to that?

Answer (score 0):

Error trace shows its not able to resolve "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Check whether dependency for mysql.jar is provided in class path. If its maven project check pom.xml for mysql dependency provided

Answer (score -1):

Just download "ojdbc7.jar" and import that jar to your project.

Comment: ojdbc7 is for Oracle, the error indicates the OP wants to use MySQL...

Comment: Sorry i meant mysql-connector-java-8.x.jar